# zero-divisor and unit for a direct product

Tags: ring-theory

Describe all units and zero-divisor of the ring $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Q}.$

Note $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Q}=\left \{ \left ( x,\frac{p}{q} \right ) \mid x\in\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{P} \in \mathbb{Z}, q\neq 0 \in\mathbb{Z} \right \}$
The unit of  $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Q}$ is an element with a multiplicative inverse.

That is $\left ( 1,\frac{q}{p} \right ) \forall q,p\neq 0\in \mathbb{Z}$

Is this right?

How should I determine the zero-divisor? Any hint for this is appreciated.

Comment: Note that in $\mathbb Z$, $-1$ has a multiplicative inverse too. So the units are $(\pm 1,\dfrac qp)$

Comment: Note that individually $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q$ have no zero divisors except for zero itself. How can you piece this together to get zero divisors in the product?

Comment: Helpful reminder.

Comment: For zero-divisor, the zero in the ring is $(0,0)$. Consider the product $(a,0)\times (0,b)$